# Getting values from a text file then having them placed into a list with no duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, list, dictionary

What I have is a program that will read a text file that has data from a file that is in the format

```
`FootballTeamName1 : FootballTeamName2 : FootballTeam1Score : FootballTeam2Score
```

Currently it reads in the file and will split it at each colon what I want to know is how would I make it so that each time it comes across a name then it will add that name to the list if it doesn't already exist or if it does then it will not create a duplicate value rather it will add the values to the values that already exist for that teams name.

I currently have a program that can get the values for when you search for a team but what I want to do is make it so that it is possible when the user does not specify a team then it will make it so that it will return the results for all of the teams. Here is what I have currently which asks for the location of the file and asks the user for specifying a file which works but I'm not sure how to do what I want.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class reader {

//used to count the number of invalid and valid matches

public static boolean verifyFormat(String[] words) {
    boolean valid = true;
    if (words.length != 4) { 
        valid = false;
    } else if (words[0].isEmpty() || words[0].matches("\\s+")) {
        valid = false;
    } else if ( words[1].isEmpty() || words[1].matches("\\s+")) {
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid && isInteger(words[2]) && isInteger(words[3]);}

//checks to see that the number of items in the file are equal to the four needed and the last 2 are integers
//also checks to make sure that there are no results that are just whitespace

public static boolean isInteger( String input ) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt( input );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        return false;
    }
}
//checks to make sure that the data is an integer

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(true){ //Runs until it is specified to break

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter filename");
        String UserFile = sc.nextLine();
        File file = new File(UserFile);
        if(!file.exists()) {
          continue;
        }

        if(UserFile != null && !UserFile.isEmpty()){ 
            System.out.println("Do you want to generate plain (T)ext or (H)TML");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase("H") ) {
                processFile(UserFile)   ;           }
            else if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase("T")){
                  processFile(UserFile);
            }
                  else{
                        System.out.println("Do you want to generate plain (T)ext or (H)TML");


                    }

        }
      }
    }

//checks how the user wants the file to be displayed 

private static void processFile(String UserFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String hteam;
    String ateam;
    int hscore;
    int ascore;
    int totgoals = 0;
    int gamesplayed = 0;
    int gs = 0;
    int gc = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int l = 0;
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");//This will retrieve line separator dependent on OS.


    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(UserFile))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the name of the team you want the results for");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();


    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        String[] words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");
        //splits the file at colons

        if(verifyFormat(words)) {
            hteam = words[0];       // read the home team
            ateam = words[1];       // read the away team
            hscore = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);       //read the home team score
            totgoals = totgoals + hscore;
            ascore = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);       //read the away team score
            totgoals = totgoals + ascore;

             if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase(hteam)){
                 gamesplayed = gamesplayed + 1;
                 gs = gs + hscore;
                 gc = gc + ascore;
                 if (hscore > ascore)
                     w = w + 1;
                 else if (ascore > hscore)
                     l = l + 1;
                 else
                     d = d + 1;
             }
             else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(ateam)){
                 gamesplayed = gamesplayed + 1;
                 gs = gs + ascore;
                 gc = gc + hscore;
                 if (hscore < ascore)
                     w = w + 1;
                 else if (ascore < hscore)
                     l = l + 1;
                 else
                     d = d + 1;
             }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(input + newLine + "--------------------------" + newLine + "Games played: " + gamesplayed +   newLine + "Games Won: " + w + newLine + "Games Drawn: " + d + newLine + "Games Lost: " + l + newLine + "Goals For: " + gs + newLine + "Goals Against: " + gc);   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want no duplicate elements in your collection use a Set.  A Set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements (doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the entries into a Set (or if you want them sorted - SortedSet). Since Set only holds unique values - you'll always have only one "copy" of each value.

For reference, the following code uses 5 values, but the set will have only 3 (unique) values:

```
String str = "A : B : C : B : A";
String[] vals = str.split(":");
SortedSet<String> myVals = new TreeSet<String>();
for(String val : vals)
{
    myVals.add(val.trim());
}

System.out.println("Set size: " + myVals.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a Map from Team to Score, where if the team already exists, then get the value from the map, and and the score to that.

Comment: After reading about it I know how to add it to a map but I don't know how to only add the correct ones, how would I make it so that it will add the first teams name then the score rather than adding all of the values into the map?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you want a list of results, just do a Map from Team to a list of scores